# Using wildcard in 'ls' command to find files containing uppercase letters only

Tags: ls, wildcards, case-sensitivity

So I've been playing around with filesystem and wondered about listing the files in `/etc` that contains only upper-case letters in their names. I commanded

```
ls *[A-Z]*
```

But the console shows the files containing lower chars too. 
I want to use only `ls` command. Is the console program locale dependent?

What is the underlying cause?

Comment: Do you want  file names with no lower case letter (like `ABC.TXT`, `123.C++`, `.123`) or files that has no other character than uppercase characters (like `ABC` but not `ABC.TXT` which contains a `.` which is not an uppercase letter.

Comment: I want file names containing Upper case letters no matter where they occur :)

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. `Foo.txT` also contains uppercase letters.

Comment: If you complain about your shell showing "the files containing lower chars too", I assume it matters where they occur. For example, they should not occur before or after lowercase letters?!

Comment: *"Is the console program Locale dependent?"* Yes, shells depend on your locale, which may specify a lexicographic ordering that intersperses upper- and lower-case letters, and that's the underlying cause of your problem. [Use `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389071) Based on [that comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389055#comment692991_389055), I don't think you want to match just *all*-upper-case names, but if so you should [combine `[[:upper:]]` with an extended glob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389067). I suggest you *[edit]* for clarification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*`[A-Z]` doesn't mean upper case. It means letters from `A` to `Z`, which may include lower-case letters. Usually you should use `[[:upper:]]` instead. (This works in Bash even without `extglob`.)*

#### What characters `[A-Z]` matches depends on your locale.

You [have clarified](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389055/using-wildcard-in-ls-command-to-find-files-containing-uppercase-letters-only/389071#comment692991_389055) that you want to show all filenames that  contain at least on upper-case character anywhere--not only filenames consisting entirely of upper case--but that when you use `ls *[A-Z]*`, you get some filenames that don't have *any* upper-case characters in them.

This happens when your locale's lexicographic ordering interperses upper- and lower-case letters (e.g., AaBbCcDd...). Although you can set another locale (e.g., `LC_ALL=C`), the best solution is usually to write a pattern that specifically matches upper-case letters.

*Which characters are upper-case letters* may also vary between locales, but presumably if something is an upper-case letter in your locale then you want to include it. So that's probably an advantage of `[[:upper:]]` rather than a disadvantage.

#### Use `[[:upper:]]` instead.

Most Bourne-style shells, such as Bash, support POSIX character classes in globs. This command will list entries in `/etc` whose names have at least one upper-case letter:

```
ls -d /etc/*[[:upper:]]*
```

Some of the entries you get may be directories. If you want to show their contents rather than just list the directories, then you can remove the `-d` flag. You may also want to put a `--` flag before the pattern, in case you have entries in `/etc` that begin with `-`. You probably don't, though. (In a script, you will usually want to use `--` here.)

#### You probably don't want dotfiles, but if you do...

This will not show entries that start with `.`. Usually you don't want to show them. If you do want them, most shells allow you to write a single glob that also matches them or to configure globbing to include them by default. The option to automatically include leading-`.` entries in Bash is `dotglob` and it can be enabled with `shopt -s dotglob`. For other shells see 
. Or you can simply write a second glob for them:

```
ls -d /etc/*[[:upper:]]* /etc/.*[[:upper:]]*
```

Most popular Bourne-style shells support brace expansions, so you can write this more compactly with less repetition:

```
ls -d /etc/{,.}*[[:upper:]]*
```

In most shells including Bash, when you write two separate globs, you'll get an error message when either one does not expand--because the default behavior in most shells is to pass it unexpanded. But `ls` will still show the entries that matched the other one. But [as Stéphane Chazelas has pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389055/using-wildcard-in-ls-command-to-find-files-containing-uppercase-letters-only/389071#comment693014_389071), **in some shells including the very popular Zsh, the whole command fails and `ls` is never run.** If you're using the shell interactively this is not really harmful, because you can modify the command run it again, but such constructions are unsuitable for portable scripts. Bash will also behave this way if you set the `failglob` shell option.

#### You don't need extended globbing for that.

In Bash you do not need to have extended globbing enabled to use POSIX character classes in glob patterns. On my system with Bash 4.3.48:

```
ek@Io:~$ shopt extglob
extglob         off
ek@Io:~$ ls -d /etc/*[[:upper:]]*
/etc/ConsoleKit     /etc/LatexMk         /etc/ODBCDataSources  /etc/UPower
/etc/ImageMagick-6  /etc/NetworkManager  /etc/rcS.d            /etc/X11
```

#### But you do need it to match filenames of *only* upper-case letters.

What you *do* need extended globbing for is if you want to match filenames consisting *only* of upper-case letters. Then you would use `+([[:upper:]])` or `*([[:upper:]])`, and those are extended globs.

If you're using Bash, see [this article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing), [this guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob), [3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) in the [GNU Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) for details. See also [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389067/11938).

Comment: Note that `ls -d /etc/*[[:upper:]]* /etc/.*[[:upper:]]*` will fail the command if _either_ pattern fails to match in `zsh`, `fish` or `bash -o failglob` and if both fail in `csh`/`tcsh` (`{,.}` comes from `csh` btw) or pre-Bourne shells (but would otherwise not cause an error if only one of them fails there as it would then be removed). Also note that in other shells, if there's no file matching `/etc/*[[:upper:]]*` but there's a file called literally `/etc/*[[:upper:]]*` there, it will be listed (even though it doesn't contain any uppercase letter).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good point. I'm not too worried about listing `/etc/*[[:upper:]]*` since it's an `ls` command which the OP is presumably going to inspect themselves rather than automatically parsing, and if they've set `bash -o failglob` they likely know they've done so. But that some other shells--including the very popular `zsh`!--default to `failglob`-like behavior is a major limitation of including a glob that cannot expand and something I had failed to consider. (I've now edited to warn about this explicitly.)

Comment: See also [Why is nullglob not default?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)

Answer (score 3):

#### For file names consisting solely of uppercase letter.

(like `FOO`, `ÉTÉ`, `ΛΈΞΗ`; unlike `FOO.BAR`, `ÉTÉ` (where that `É` is written as `E` followed by a U+0301 combining acute accent¹))

With `ksh` or `zsh -o kshglob -o nobareglobqual` or `bash -O extglob`:

```
ls -d +([[:upper:]])
```

With `zsh -o extendedglob` (which you'd rather use than `kshglob`):

```
ls -d [[:upper:]]#
```

Or with GNU `ls` (assuming file names only contain valid characters):

```
ls --ignore='*[^[:upper:]]*'
```

Or with `find` instead of `ls` (which here just outputs its arguments, I'd expect you'd want to use options like `-l` for it to be useful):

```
find . ! -name . -prune -name '*' ! -name '*[^[:upper:]]*'
```

(the `-name '*'` is to filter out the filenames that contain invalid characters, which the next `! -name` would not be able to filter out (with some `find` implementations at least))

#### for file names without lowercase letters

(but still allow non-letters like in `ABC.TXT`), with `ksh`:

```
(FIGNORE='@(.|..|*[[:lower:]]*)'; ls -d -- *)
```

With `bash -O dotglob -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob -o dotglob -o nobareglobqual`:

```
ls -d -- !(*[[:lower:]]*)
```

Or `zsh -o extendedglob`:

```
ls -d -- ^*[[:lower:]]*(D)
```

Or with GNU `ls` (assuming file names only contain valid characters):

```
ls -A --ignore='*[[:lower:]]*' --ignore='.*[[:lower:]]*'
```

(the fact that the extra `--ignore='.*[[:lower:]]*'` is needed seems like a bug to me)

With `find`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -name '*' ! -name '*[[:lower:]]*'
```

(with some `find` implementations, does not include filenames with invalid characters even if none of the valid characters are lower case ones).

#### For file names with at least one uppercase letter:

(like `Foo.bar`, `.Été.txt`, unlike `123.6`, `foo.bar`)

With `zsh -o dotglob` or `bash -O dotglob` (the `dotglob` being to include files whose name starts with `.`):

```
ls -d -- *[[:upper:]]*
```

With `find`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -name '*[[:upper:]]*'
```

(with some `find` implementations, does not include filenames with invalid characters even if some of the valid characters are uppercase ones)

---

¹ To allow combining characters, with `zsh -o pcrematch`, you could use a perl-like regular expression making use of Unicode character properties:

```
ls -d -- *(e@'[[ $REPLY =~ "^(?>\p{Lu}\pM*)*$" ]]'@)
```

Comment: This answers *all* the questions the OP could be asking, for *most* of the popular shells they could be using! +1

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use only ls? You can simply use find instead:
`find -regex './[A-Z]+'`

EDIT:
According to `man 7 glob`:

> **Wildcard matching**
>   A string is a wildcard pattern if it contains one of the characters '?', '*' or '['.  Globbing is the operation that expands a
>   wildcard pattern into the list of pathnames matching the pattern. 
>   Matching is defined by:
>
> A '?' (not between brackets) matches any single character.
>
> A '*' (not between brackets) matches any string, including the empty string.
>
> **Character classes**
>
> An  expression  "[...]"  where  the first character after the leading '[' is not an '!' matches a single character, namely any of
>   the characters enclosed by the brackets.
>
> **Regular expressions**
>   Note  that  wildcard  patterns  are  not  regular expressions,
>   although they are a bit similar.  First of all, they match filenames,
>   rather than text, and secondly, the conventions are not the same: for
>   example, in a regular        expression '*' means zero or more copies
>   of the preceding thing.
>
> Now that regular expressions have bracket expressions where the
>   negation is indicated by a '^', POSIX has declared the effect of a
>   wildcard pattern "[^...]" to be undefined.

If you want to use ls you have to bear in mind that bash won't translate your '*' in the same way as `find -regexp` or `grep`. *[A-Z]* will try to match any string followed by uppercase letter followed by any string so basically any string.

Comment: just out of curiousity and because it is not working?

Comment: `-regex` or a `find` without file argument are GNU extensions. Also note that `./[A-Z]+` is also a glob for the shell which should be quoted. If you do `touch ./A+`, if will stop working. Like for shell globs, what `[A-Z]` matches depends on the locale and generally doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for the previous answer, I didn't have my coffee yet.

I am unsure about doing this with just ls.
But, here's another grep that should do the trick:

ls | egrep ^[^a-z0-9]*$

Answer (score 0):

The pattern of your command will match any filename with at least one uppercase letter: `Foo` or `bAr` will match, because the `*` can match everything before or after the uppercase letter. That's why you get also get files with *also*  lowercase letters in the name.

If you want files with only uppercase letters, you need `extglob` in `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

and then do

```
ls *([A-Z])
```

You may also need to set your locale to `C` or use `[:upper:]` instead of `A-Z`

Comment: Wether `[A-Z]` includes only uppercase letters depends on the locale. On GNU systems, and with `bash` and in most non-C locales, `[A-Z]` would also include the b-z English letters in addition to other non-English letters.

Comment: I'm not sure about "most", but I added it to the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a filename globbing pattern on the command line, not just with `ls`, it's the shell that expands it to any matching names, not the command.

This means that `ls *[A-Z]*` isn't just using `ls`, it's also using the shell, which does the actual filename expansion.

To use only *one* command to find all the names in the current directory that consists solely of uppercase ASCII characters, you would have to resort to `find` (GNU `find` used here):

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '^\./[A-Z]*$' -print
```

Change `-print` to `-ls` for an `ls -l` -like list.

There is no standard shell *globbing* pattern that may be used to find filenames with *only* uppercase characters, although `bash` (which I assume is what you're using) has extensions to these patterns to some that may, as you can see in some of the other answers. These extensions originally come from the AT&T `ksh` shell.

The pattern that you're using here, `*[A-Z]*`, will expand to all names consisting of at *least one uppercase character*.